# Misaligment while formatting with escape t "\t"

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm learning Python through "Python Projects for Beginners" by Connor Milliken. In the first project "Creating a Recipt Printing Program" there is this section

```
# creating a product and price for three itens
p1_name, p1_price = "Books", 49.95
p2_name, p2_price = "Computer", 579.99
p3_name, p3_price = "Monitor", 124.89

# create a print statement for each product
print("\t{}\t\t${}".format(p1_name.title(), p1_price))
print("\t{}\t\t${}".format(p2_name.title(), p2_price))
print("\t{}\t\t${}".format(p3_name.title(), p3_price))
```

The lines are equal but for the second line the price is misaligned as if it has another \t. The problem was the same in jupyter notebook and Atom + terminal. If you just delete one '\t' the problem is solved but you can't really understand what happened.

Comment: Although unfortunately none of the answers there explain *why* there is a misalignment.

Comment: Show a sample output with the error, and what you want instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of a tab as inserting a specific number of spaces in the string (it doesn't). Instead, you are giving control over whoever *displays* the string, since they are the ones that decide where the tab stops are.

If you want precise control, use fixed-width padded format specifiers instead. For example,

```
print("        {:>10} {:>6}".format(p1_name.title(), p1_price))
```

This assumes that 10 characters is wide enough for *any* title and 6 characters is wide enough for any price.